# Подсчет количества элементов в скользящем окне по столбцу pandas

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть столбцы датафрейма pandas:

> D['L'] = [1,1,1,1,1,9,3,1,1,1,1,1,1]
>
> D['K'] = [1,1,1,1,5,1,5,2,1,1,1,1,1]

Как получить столбец с к-вом элементов в столбце 'K' больших по значению, чем в столбце 'L' из последних 4, на скользящем окне.
Результат:

> D['C'] = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,3,2,2,1,0,0]

Не работает:

```
D['C'] = D['L'].rolling(4, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x.gt(D['K']).sum())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При df:

```
    L  K
0   1  1
1   1  1
2   1  1
3   1  1
4   1  5
5   9  1
6   3  5
7   1  2
8   1  1
9   1  1
10  1  1
11  1  1
12  1  1
```

я бы предложил сделать так:

```
df["C"] = ((df["K"] - df["L"]).gt(0)).rolling(4, min_periods=1).sum().astype("int")
```

тогда df["C"] будет:

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     3
8     2
9     2
10    1
11    0
12    0
```